# istio 1.17 SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, istio-operator

created ssl certificate and imported into istio gateway and virtual service up and running fine. while accessing with curl from ingressateway ip it showing error.

curl https://abb936882d5594ab0b76d7c059cf64f6-1086964687.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9443
curl: (60) schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: my-gateway
spec:
selector:
istio: ingressgateway
servers:
- port:
number: 9443
name: http
protocol: HTTPS
tls:
mode: SIMPLE
credentialName: mysuperdomain-certs
hosts:
- '*'
- port:
number: 7443
name: http-two
protocol: HTTPS
tls:
mode: SIMPLE
credentialName: mysuperdomain-certs
hosts:
- '*'
- port:
number: 6443
name: http-three
protocol: HTTPS
tls:
mode: SIMPLE
credentialName: mysuperdomain-certs
hosts:
- '*'

virtualservice.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
name: my-virtualservice
spec:
hosts:
- '*'
gateways:
- my-gateway
http:
- match:
- port: 9443
route:
- destination:
host: httpbin-one.default.svc.cluster.local
port:
number: 9443
- match:
- port: 7443
route:
- destination:
host: httpbin-two.default.svc.cluster.local
port:
number: 7443
- match:
- port: 6443
route:
- destination:
host: httpbin-three.default.svc.cluster.local
port:
number: 6443

how to fix this error. Istio installed in eks application work with TLS ( ISTIO ssl created with this command kubectl create secret tls mysuperdomain-certs -n istio-system --key cert/cert.pem --cert cert/key.pem ).

Comment: My guess is you're using self-signed certificates.

Comment: did you konw how to solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: can you explain the problem. ill try?